# How to avoid FileNotFoundException? How to check if a file is accessible/exists in Android?

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception

I have a problem with java.io.FileNotFoundException. Sometimes I get this exception, sometimes not. I don't know why, because the specified file exists. I think the file might be used by another app, or by the system.

How can I know when the file exists/is accessible for reading/writing ?

Thank you.

The error log:

IOKt Error java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.vending/files/20170321_161318.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [File.exists()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()). But your code should be able to handle a FileNotFoundException. Also you should really investigate why you are getting it in the first place (maybe the exception's message would contain a clue), since it could be caused by a mistake in your code.

Comment: I use Okio to retrieve the file source. Okio.source(file). I got the exception there.

Comment: Did you try using the [File.exists()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) ? You can also use [File.canRead()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead()) and [File.canWrite()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite()) to check the permissions.

Comment: I have but when I use those motheds the System labels many files which I transferred earlier as invalid. So it is not OK.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileNotFoundException` document explain that:

> This exception will be thrown by the {@link FileInputStream}, {@link
>     FileOutputStream}, and {@link RandomAccessFile} constructors when a file
>     with the specified pathname does not exist.  **It will also be thrown by these
>     constructors if the file does exist but for some reason is inaccessible, for
>     example when an attempt is made to open a read-only file for writing**.

So you should make sure you have the permission of the file,like `canRead()`,`canWrite()` method in `java.io.File` class.

Comment: I have     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @RaulTunduc I am not good at android,but you can use the 'canRead` and `canWrite` to determine the file permission.

Comment: I used that in the provider and there are so many files that are labeld as ,,invalid", but those file are OK, because I had transferred them earlier